# CORS policy not workign Laravel 9, Angular 14, Plesk Centos, Php 8.1

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors, plesk

My application keeps returning the CORS error. I've followed every solution on the internet but havent found the right answer yet.

**Console Errors:**
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.domain/api/v1/status' from origin 'https://domain.nl' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

**main.js console error:**
*"Http failure response for https://api.domain/api/v1/status: 0 Unknown Error"*

Strange thing: the data is loaded and shown in the app. So it looks like OPTIONS is failing but the actual xhr request is working.

- My server is Plesk based with Centos. Here I run php 8.1 on a Dedicated FPM application served by nginx.
- pm.max_children is set to 20

I've tried the following solutions:

1. Add headers via Plesk > Apache & Nginx settings in Additional directives for HTTPS:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

2. Add headers via Plesk > Apache & Nginx settings in Additional nginx directives:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
```

3. In Laravel added the cors middleware by adding cors to all routes

```
Turn:
->middleware('api','auth:sanctum')
Into:
->middleware('cors','api','auth:sanctum')
```

4. in Laravel downloaded the fruitcake/laravel-cors package
5. Added the header to all response() returns

```
return response()
    ->json(['Count'=>$result['count'], 'Result'=>$collection])
    ->withCallback($request->input('callback'))
    ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*");
```

6. Changed the config of cors.php

```
This:
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
Into:
'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

And this:
'supports_credentials' => false,
Into:
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

NONE of these solutions work! please help me

p.s. need to mention that a developemnt setup works fine. This is a locally run angular (localhost:4200) connected to a domain run on the SAME server as the test application is running also in Plesk > Centos > Php8.1 FPM served by nginx.

p.p.s. yes i've run composer dump-autoload, artisan optimize and artisan cache:clear many times in between

After consulting phpnl slack ive added the following solution

7. added the laravel Cors Middleware in Kernel.php

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

In the server Logs I see the following error keeps comming up:

2785#0: *3791483 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream

I've added a Let's Encrypt free certificate. and reissued it. This did not help. And the same error keeps showing.

Response for JubOps:
This is the code making the request

```
  getRequest(url: string, requestParams: any = {}): Observable<any> {
    const headerDict = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + environment.authData.plainTextToken,
      'X-UserId': environment.authData.curUser['UserId'].toString()
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict),
      params: requestParams
    };

    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + url, requestOptions);
  }
```

this is a screenshot of the console:
[image]

And here a screenshot of the logs in Plesk:
[image]

Here a screenshot of the network tab
[image]

Comment: Your backend is running sanctum there are some configurations you can make to handle this error. Try to go for that solution first. The second solution is something only a systems administrator can do. On the Linux server you can fix this error as well

Comment: Edit your question and show the client code that sends the request, and also add screenshots of the problematic request/response from your browser's Network tab.

Comment: @jub0bs i've added the requested code + screenshots

Comment: @RuudvandeVen Network tab, not console tab.

Comment: @jub0bs excuse me, added now.

Comment: @RuudvandeVen Sure, but that new screenshot is not showing any details about the problematic CORS request. Click on it and take a new screenshot.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't want screenshots of textual question details.  Where possible, please replace all screenshots with copy-pasted text.